Money-obsessed guy doing Ponzi scheme, 70s or 80s, UK
Does anyone know more about the following:
Seen probably in the early 1980s, broadcasted on Dutch or Belgian TV,
a UK TV production (BBC? Nigel Havers? - I couldn't find it in IMDB, though).
Plot (from memory, so there could be some inaccuracies):
A guy becomes, basically, a psychiatric patient, because his father told him always to master over money ('never allow money to become master over you').
He somehow gets himself into running a ponzi scheme. Eventually he ends up in jail, but even there he can't stay out of trouble: a muscular inmate has heard that 'he is so good with money', and insists to make more money from his life-savings, despite all warnings and protests from the side of the sicko.
At the end, you see the guy, standing in his cell, remembering his fathers words, burning up his 'clients' money with a cigarette-lighter. 
Any ideas?
